# Type 'INTERVAL' are not supported in Spark SQL 2.4.3 - What is workaround?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**EDIT** : **Apparently Spark 2.4.3 does not support INTERVAL. I cannot upgrade to Spark 3.0.0 for the time being (admin policy). I was wondering if there is a workaround or alternating approach for INTERVAL at the moment? Thanks**

Running a query on Spark sql in Databricks and the query shows an error on interval line. I am trying to left-join the table on itself on the same user ID and having a one-month difference in users.

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
Literals of type 'INTERVAL' are currently not supported.
```

Does not Spark SQL support the interval function?

Here is my try:

```
%sql


;WITH act_months AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE_TRUNC('month', data_date) ::DATE AS act_month,
    user_id
  FROM user_sessions)

SELECT
  prev.act_month,
  prev.user_id,
  curr.user_id IS NULL AS churned_next_month
FROM act_months AS prev
LEFT JOIN act_months AS curr
  ON prev.user_id = curr.user_id
 AND prev.act_month = (curr.act_month - INTERVAL '1 MONTH')
ORDER BY prev.act_month ASC, prev.user_id ASC;
```

here is my data structure

```
+----------+----------+
| data_date|   user_id|
+----------+----------+
|2020-01-01|22600560aa|  
|2020-01-01|17148900ab|     
|2020-01-01|21900230aa|    
|2020-01-01|35900050ac|    
|2020-01-01|22300280ad|     
|2020-01-02|19702160ac|     
|2020-02-02|17900020aa|    
|2020-02-02|16900120aa|    
|2020-02-02|11160900aa|    
|2020-03-02|16900290aa|    
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: What version of Spark are you running? Have you enabled ANSI Compliance mode?

Comment: Spark does support `INTERVAL` but you need to be running version 3.0.0 or later and in ANSI Compliant Mode for ISO SQL-2011.

Comment: Running Spark 2.4.3

Comment: Then you need to upgrade to Spark 3.0.0 for `INTERVAL` support.

Comment: @Dai Do I we have any alternative approach that works with Spark 2.4.3 , instead of INTERVAL

Comment: Use `DATEDIFF`, which is supported by at least Spark 2.3.0: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#datediff

Comment: I'm not a Spark user, can you explain what the `::DATE` syntax in your CTE means?

Comment: What is the schema of the `user_sessions` table? I think  you can greatly simplify your query.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ADD_MONTHS`, not `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: Thanks man, `ADD_MONTHS` was a great workaround. ( `::DATE` simply convert data type in sql , from X to date format - convert to numeric  `:: NUMERIC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I am not a Spark user - and this is me reposting my comment as an answer):

- From my reading of Spark's documentation, `INTERVAL` is only supported by Spark 3.0.0 or later.

  - You said you're running Spark 2.4.3, so `INTERVAL` is not supported in your system.
- However you can use `ADD_MONTHS` (and `DATE_ADD`) which is supported [by (at least) Spark 2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html).

Try this:

```
;WITH q AS (

    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        DATE_TRUNC( data_date, 'month' ) AS act_year_month, -- DATE_TRUNC( $dt, 'month' ) returns a datetime value with only the YEAR and MONTH components set, all other components are zeroed out.
        user_id
    FROM
        user_sessions
)

SELECT
    prev.act_year_month,
    prev.user_id,
    ( curr.user_id IS NULL ) AS churned_next_month
FROM
    q AS prev
    LEFT JOIN q AS curr ON
        prev.user_id = curr.user_id
        AND
        prev.act_year_month = ADD_MONTHS( curr.act_year_month, -1 )

ORDER BY
    prev.act_year_month,
    prev.user_id;
```